# Manually save Bitmap or ByteArray into cache and manually delete one cache image using image url

Tags: android, android-glide

1. When I upload an image to server, I want to cache it in storage in Glide with Bitmap or ByteArray so once it is uploaded, I do not have to download it from server. I can achieve this using SDWebImage in iOS, but I can't find how to do this in Glide.

   [((SDImageCache *)webImageManager.imageCache) storeImage:image forKey:downloadURL completion:nil];
2. Is there a way to manually delete just one cached image using one ImageURL? If image isn't needed again, I want to delete it from the user's device so it doesn't use user's device memory. Here too I can achieve this using SDWebImage in iOS, but I can't find how to do this in Glide.

   [((SDImageCache *)webImageManager.imageCache) removeImageForKey:imageUrl withCompletion:nil];

Thank you for your expertise

Comment: If you upload files from your device then why also storing some bitmap somewhere. If you wanna run out of storage soon then save bitmaps.

Comment: I want to store locally so I don’t have to download it from the server using glide. It cost money for each downloads using Firebase.

Comment: I was commenting your use of bitmaps.

Comment: So I can cache it and upload it. That’s not relevant to the question.

Comment: There is a chance that your image that you are uploading gets deleted from the library. That's why I cache it to account for all corner cases. But that's not my question (but an answer)

Answer (score 1):

There is no interface in glide(or other image caching libs) to delete particular image from cache. You can clear entire cache.
But you can skip caching in glide for particular image URI
Use **diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)** to avoid disk caching and **skipMemoryCache()** to avoid caching in memory.
for more information on glide caching
http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html#cache-invalidation

Comment: Thank you for answering 1 out of 2 questions - it is disappointing that Glide doesn't have that simple feature though like in SDWebImage for iOS. The more important question is the 1st question. Is there a way to save Bitmap (or byteArray or local file) to cache manually to a url? So that next time when you load that url from server, Glide will intellectually detect that it is already cached and won't make the network call at all. This is important because I do not want the users who upload images to download them too - necessary cost for my server database which cost per download.

Comment: If you could answer the 2nd question, the bounty is yours ;)